# Stack widget delete & add views dynamicly Android 3.0

Tags: android, stack, widget, android-3.0-honeycomb

Can anyone give me an example of using a Stack Widget and being able to remove and add views dynamically.

Here is an example.

1) Widget loads and you add 4 views to the widget 
2) User loads and activity within the same widget package and uses a button to delete one of the 4 views.

I need an example how to do that.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 3):

Your `StackView` widget should have an implemntation of the `RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory` interface which includes the `onDataSetChanged()` method.  Within this method you need to update the widget from your data source.

Then in your application, any time your data set changes you can then tell any instances of your widget to refresh themselves by calling:

> AppWidgetManager awm =
>   AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getActivity());
>   awm.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(awm.getAppWidgetIds(new
>   ComponentName(getActivity(),
>   Your_App_Widget_Provider.class)),
>   R.id.your_stack_view);